# Visual Studio 2012 error: The attempted operation is not supported with this database version

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

I am trying to connect to a SQL server 2008 SSIS package from my computer. I am using visual studio 2012. When I try to add an existing packaged, I get the error in the link below.

What do I need to install for this to be compatible?

Comment: Seems to be several answers here. https://www.google.com/search?q=The+attempted+operation+is+not+supported+with+this+database+version&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: Thank you @destination-data

Answer (score 0):

To edit 2008 packages you need [BIDS (Business Intelligence Development Studio)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173767(v=sql.105).aspx).

BIDS runs within Visual Studio 2008.  Later updates to Visual Studio do not support older versions of SSIS.

BIDS was replaced by [SSDT-BI (SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj856966(v=sql.120).aspx).  The current version of SSDT-BI is the first to offer backwards compatibility with SSIS (although it only supports SSIS 2012, 2014 and 2016, not 2008 or 2008 R2).

Microsoft has published this [handy document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/install-windows/installing-integration-services-versions-side-by-side).  It details which development environment you should use for each version of SQL Server.